# Wifi and does not work in my webview

Tags: android, webview

I have made a webview which loads my web page. When only wifi is enabled, it works fine. If only 3G is enabled it also works fine. But when both are enabled at the same time, the webview won't load the page. How to fix this?

I have these settings for the webview

```
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

I don't know if I need all of these permissions in my manifest, but these are the ones i have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi"></uses-feature>
```

Comment: I use the same code and it works for both WIFI/3G for me . Try to have only this permission "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>" & remove other permissions and it might work (couldn't find another reason for this problem !!)

Comment: Same problem:( But it is a pretty strange problem. If i turn off 3G and let Wifi on, wifi does not work. Still does not work if I turn off and on wifi. When i turn off wifi and enable 3G, and then turn on wifi and disable 3G, wifi works.